# How to change UTF-8 characters to Persian in C#

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, character, decoding

Hello i want convert this characters to persian or arabic characters

> %D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the character encoding scheme used in URLs. Searching for "C# URL decode" (or similar terms) on the web yields the documentation for [`System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode). Using this method to decode the example string in your question results in: سلام